# Setting SelectedIndex -1 ASP.NET DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, .net

Is there a way to select -1 index without adding a `new ListItem("", "-1",true))` from code behind like jQuery does?

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/eL8sn/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

That's how one usually does it from code-behind.

ETA:  I now see what you are talking about.  And I'm afraid I don't see how it can be done from server side.  All you can do on the server side is control the rendering.  As far as I can tell, even if you render this code:

```
<select id="testSelect" selectedIndex="-1">
```

... it still appears with the top option appearing to be selected.

It looks as if only by explicitly setting it to -1 with javascript after rendering will it appear with absolutely nothing selected.  It *appears* as if it can't be done declaratively in HTML.

If you can find a way to write the tag in HTML so that it appears this way on load, then you could tweak the rendering in code-behind (using `.AddAttribute()` or similar) but if it can't be done with a declaration, it'll need javascript.

(You could of course write a jQuery snippet to change all your dropdowns to selectedIndex = -1, but you'll have thought of that!)

Comment: It doesnt Work, always stay in index 0

Comment: What happens?  What do you *want* to happen that doesn't happen, to be precise?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Let me get back to you on that.

Comment: @ I used DropDownList1.Attributes.Add("selectedIndex", "-1") but it doesnt work. I will create a function in the client side to do that.  Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you're binding it on **Page_Load** event it does a post back **`(AutoPostBack='True')`**.It will simply rebind ever time the index is changed

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{  
    BindDropDownList1();      
}
```

(or)

If the above solution dosen't work try to add an empty item as shown:

```
this.myDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select...", ""));
```

Comment: Nope, i dont want to add a new ListItem, please look how jQuery does http://jsfiddle.net/eL8sn/

Comment: JQuery is a client side code but you're trying to do it from codebhind which is server side.You have to do it either way or try to use a normal html control and use ajax for that.

Comment: SelectedIndex is the same property from codebehind or client side, when .NET render a DropDownList it will be rendered like a normal html control.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

string selectStr = "SELECT";
string allStr = "ALL"

ListItem allLI = new ListItem(allStr,allStr);
ListItem selectLI = new ListItem(selectStr,selectStr);

DropDownList.Items.Add(selectLI);
DropDownList.Items.Add(allLI);

//code to fill the DropDownList with the list that your query returns

DropDownList.SelectedValue = selectStr;

Comment: Please read the question "without adding a new ListItem" thanks anyway